# Selenium Unable to enter Paypal Sandbox Details

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, paypal

I am trying to get my Selenium test to Paypal test Details in order to automate Paypal Testing

I can navigate to the Sandbox.Paypal page but once there I cannot get Selenium to Automate Email and Password entry and clicking the Login Button. I am writing in C# on Visual Studio.

My code currently for this step is

```
                    driver.Instance.SwitchTo().Frame("injectedUl");

                    By AtPaypal = By.CssSelector("#loginSection > div.pr.row-fluid > xo-title > h1");
                    new WebDriverWait(driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(AtPaypal));

                    var email = driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Name("login_email"));
                    email.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
                    email.SendKeys("xxxxxxxxxx");

                    var Password = driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Name("login_password"));
                    Password.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
                    Password.SendKeys("xxxxxxxxxx");

                    var Login = driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("btnLogin"));
                    Login.Click();

                    By Paypal = By.Id("confirmButtonTop");
                    new WebDriverWait(driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(Paypal));

                    var ContinueBtn = driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("confirmButtonTop"));

                    ContinueBtn.Click();
```

However this isn't working, any help greatly appreciated.

Regards

Richard

Comment: are you able to find the element password field and email field at all?

Comment: Since we do not see the actual html the thing that stands out is that you switched to an iframe. Is this actually in an iframe? If so, is "injectedUl" the actual name of the iframe? When you can't interact with any objects, it is either that you are interacting with the incorrect frame or the frame is not needed.

Comment: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-54365007M8453270M#/checkout/login                                  That is the web address of the Paypal Sandbox, reading about how other people solved this issue in the past led to the Iframe code, however this is not working for me. Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Richard I got this to work.

If you are not typing in the fields, you are not correctly getting to the iframe. If you run it through debug does it work? Just wondering if it is a timing issue. I would also use ID over Name.

The page object I just used the input id for the field.

Create a switchTo to to go to the iframe.

```
     public static void SwitchToIframe(string frameName)
    {
      _webDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameName);
    }
```

Piece it together...

```
    Driver.Goto("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-54365007M8453270M#/checkout/login");
        Driver.SwitchToIframe("injectedUl");
        
     var email = driver.FindElement(By.ID("email"));
                email.SendKeys("test@no.com");

                var Password = driver.FindElement(By.ID("password"));
                Password.SendKeys("xxxxxxxxxx");

                var Login = driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnLogin"));
                Login.Click();
```

Comment: Hi thanks managed to get it working myself late Friday using similar method :) but there is an answer here now for anyone who has the same issue :).

Answer (score 0):

You might try sending an Enter key in the password field instead of clicking on the login button.

Comment: Hi Matt, I cant pass the Logon and Password through to the fields at all before even getting to the logon button.